# How to transfer the cut plane near to the default fly camera in JMonkey engine?

Tags: java, 3d, jmonkeyengine

I try to use JMonkey engine (JME3) to create a scene. In the default project I use the default camera. When I render 3D models from uploaded .obj sources the engine starts to cut the objects too early when the camera nears to the object. I think I need to make smaller the distance between the real camera place and the place from which the engine starts to look into the inside volume of the model. But I can not understand which variable controls this distance.
I show the example to see how long the distance between the camera and the stairs by default.
[image]

How can I change the distance to the cutting plane?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was in the model scale. I have used the model which was scaled with parameter 0.05f (too small). When I have changed the scale to 1f (original) the near cut plane started to work correct